# Grails: Why doesn't session correctly save my list of maps?

Tags: session, grails, grails-2.0

I have list that I push `params` wnen certain pages are visited. However some items of the list don't have `action` and `controller` keys. Why isn't `session` keeping my data with full integrity?

I'm doing things like `session.setAttribute('my.key', [params])`

Comment: it's not clear, what `action and controller keys` have to do with `full integrity`. update your question

Comment: I've noticed that pages for the default action (usually index) don't register a `params.action` value unless the URL actually has `/index` on the end. Same goes for the site's main index page - it reports an empty `action` and `controller` values for `params`.

Comment: @injecteer those keys are present in `params` for every request I have checked.

Answer (score 0):

Do this before saving the params object to explicitly force action & controller into the params object:

```
params.action = actionName
params.controller = controllerName
```

Comment: Is using `actionName` preferable to `params.action`?

Comment: Yes, as you see for yourself, `actionName` is consistently available while `params.action` is not. `actionName` is [officially documented](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/actionName.html) while I can't find anything for `params.action` (which means it could in fact go away in a later Grails version).

Comment: the only problem with `controllerName` and `actionName` is, if you render the gsp directly - w/o controller, then those fields are empty

Comment: Hmm, right, makes sense, though OP is probably updating the session in a controller. But in a direct gsp render the only possible alternative would be to display/log/store something like `request.forwardURI`, right?